# Take a picture from camera

Tags: android, android-intent

i have a problem with code of take a picture and save. It crash when i launchCamera().
Can you help me please?

```
    private void launchCamera() {
     try {

         mOutputFile = File.createTempFile("prova", null);

          Intent intentCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

           intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                 Uri.fromFile(mOutputFile));

           startActivityForResult(intentCamera, CAMERA_REQUEST);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR:\n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         t.show();
     }
}
```

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: the program launch the exception and i don't know why

Comment: @Juppy That's the funniest thing I've seen logcat say.  Seriously though, copy the LogCat text and paste it on here.

Comment: 06-25 13:58:49.335: E/SensorManager(11084): registerListener :: handle = 1  name= BMA222 Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= com.example.sensori.MainActivity@4051c640
06-25 13:58:49.382: E/SensorManager(11084): =======>>>Sensor Thread RUNNING <<<========
06-25 13:58:50.015: E/SensorManager(11084): reg :: handle = 1
06-25 13:58:50.015: E/SensorManager(11084): registerListener :: handle = 1600940398  name= Linear Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000

Comment: Listener= com.example.sensori.MainActivity@4051c640
06-25 13:58:50.992: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11084): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-25 13:58:51.000: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11084): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
06-25 13:58:53.445: W/KeyCharacterMap(11084): Can't open keycharmap file
06-25 13:58:53.445: W/KeyCharacterMap(11084): Error loading keycharmap file

Comment: 06-25 13:58:53.453: W/KeyCharacterMap(11084): Using default keymap
06-25 13:59:02.656: D/dalvikvm(11084): GC_CONCURRENT freed 561K, 52% free 2818K/5767K, external 703K/1036K, paused 5ms+5ms
06-25 13:59:12.671: D/dalvikvm(11084): GC_CONCURRENT freed 400K, 52% free 2807K/5767K, external 703K/1036K, paused 4ms+6ms

Answer (score 1):

I am using this piece of code try it out  :

```
/**
 * This method is used to start the camera activity and save the image taken as the imagename passed 
 * 
 * @param imagename : this is the name of the image which will be saved 
 */
private void clickPicture(String imagename) {
    Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File cameraFolder;
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myfolder/");
    else
        cameraFolder= context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cameraFolder.exists())
        cameraFolder.mkdirs();
    String imageFileName = imagename;
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfolder/" + imageFileName);
    getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, 1);

}
```

and add the permisson in your manifest file :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't added the necessary permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Also I would suggest you to go over this blog post I wrote on this topic of taking a picture using the build-in Camera Activity:

[Take Picture with build in Camera Activity](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=590)

Answer (score 0):

To access the device camera, you must declare the CAMERA permission in your Android Manifest

Comment: i declare the camera permission yet